# Import non typescript library using ES6 import

Tags: typescript, tsx

How to import non typescript library using ES6 import statement

```
import {observable, action, computed, transaction} from "mobx";
```

and

```
import lib from "somelib"
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways depending on how the code was modularized. With well structure libraries with ES6-style module declarations, like lodash, you can use ES6 import statements as expected despite them not using TypeScript:

```
import * from "lodash" as _;
```

With other libraries, you can just `require` the library as you would normally and assign it to the import:

```
import lib = require("somelib");
```

Comment: Second option worked for me, just added a declare for require function also declare function require(name: string): any;

Thanks faraz !!!